# Notification on Feeds URL

Tags: notifications, rss, feed

I am .net developer.I need some clarification in the feeds notification.
I have some list of RSS feed url (e.g more than 100 URL).
My question is I want to develop a console application to get notification if the new item comes in any of the 100 URLS.
What is exact way to do this. Please guide me.

Can we make use of the pubsubhub protocol for this requirement or any other simple approach is available to do this.

Thanks,
Jayakumar

Answer (score 0):

Yes, PubSubHubbub is a protocol that you could use for this. Now, it's not implemented by *all* feeds out there, so you'll have to resort to polling. Another option is to use services like [Superfeedr](https://superfeedr.com) which provide a webhook mechanism to notify your application when a feed has been updated.